# Simple C login form issues

Tags: c

I'd like to perform a simple C login form using a text file that contains users. The idea is to input a username, check it against every one in the file and keep prompting for a new username until the login is successful.
The text file has one user on each line.

My problems are that if I enter any other user than the one on the first line I get a "login failed" message. Also if I try to input another username it will always fail the matching.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char loginBuffer[10];
    char testuser1[10];
    char testuser2[10];
    printf("Please provide your username for login\n");
    scanf("%s", testuser1);
    FILE *loginFile;
    loginFile = fopen("users.txt","r");
    if(!loginFile){
        printf("Could not open file");
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(loginBuffer, 7, loginFile) != NULL){
    strcpy(testuser2,loginBuffer);
        if(strcmp(testuser2, strcat(testuser1,"\n")) == 0){
            printf("Login successful, welcome %s \n",testuser1);
            break;
        }
        else{
        printf("Login Failed please provide another username\n");
        scanf(" %s", testuser1);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you ask for the name for each line in the file? Anyway, I really hope it is not even a prototype for  anything supposed to be secure.

Comment: Because my logic was take 1 line and compare it to the user input. Also no this is just an exercise

Comment: This logic does not make sense. Why would the user care how many lines your file has?

Comment: If login fails and you ask for another username, the ones you already read are "lost", meaning if your second attempt was the first line, you won't catch it. Read all users from file in an array, and then ask the user.

Comment: Temporarily remove `scanf(" %s", testuser1);` after `printf("Login Failed please provide another username\n");` and see if it works with other users.

Comment: Fiddling Bits nope didnt work

Comment: You need to check __one__ entered username against __all__ names in the list. That means that after getting the user input you need to loop and do multiple comparisons. If any one matches, you're good. But you can't say that login has failed until you have tested them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `fgets` for all input and avoid adding or removing trailing newlines.
Use a flag to indicate if a match was found.
Print the error outside the search loop if a match is not found.
If no match is found, rewind the file and ask for another user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char loginBuffer[10];
    char testuser1[10];
    int found = 0;
    FILE *loginFile;
    loginFile = fopen("users.txt","r");
    if(!loginFile){
        printf("Could not open file");
        return 1;
    }
    do {
        printf("Please provide your username for login\n");
        if ( fgets(testuser1, sizeof testuser1, stdin)) {
            found = 0;
            do {
                if(fgets(loginBuffer, sizeof loginBuffer, loginFile)){
                    if(strcmp(loginBuffer, testuser1) == 0){
                        printf("Login successful, welcome %s \n",testuser1);
                        found = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            } while ( !found);
            if ( !found) {
                printf("Login Failed please provide another username\n");
                rewind ( loginFile);
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets stdin EOF\n");
            fclose ( loginFile);
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( !found);
    fclose ( loginFile);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change on the line `if(strcmp(testuser2, strcat(testuser1,"\n")) == 0)` by `if(strcmp(testuser2, strcat(testuser1,"\n")))`.

Delete the comparison with 0, since you would be fulfilling the condition if `strcmp` returns 0 and I think you want it to be fulfilled when it is 1.

It worked for me

Comment: It worked for me as well.. but it takes every input as correct now

Comment: This is 100% backwards. `strcmp` returns `0` if the strings match, which is what the OP wants.